# Click event fired twice on touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox in a [sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) div where the click or changed event is triggered twice on touch devices but not on desktop (nor simulating touch on Firefox dev tools) for some obscure reason. The unwanted effect is the checkbox being toggled twice in a row leaving it at its original state. I mention the div is sortable because when they are made no longer sortable the checkbox works just fine. Here is the relevant part:

```
$sortable.sortable({
    items: '.sortable',
    cancel: 'input,textarea,button,select,option'
});
```

I have no idea why the sortable widget makes the click event be fired twice.

My attempts to handle this have been unsuccessful:

I've tried disabling the default behaviour of toggling a the checkbox and setting its value manually. However for some reason the checkbox won't be checked/unchecked. If I do it via console it does work:

```
// same with the "change" event
// the reason the event is bound to $sortable rather than the inputs themselves is that 
// new sortable divs are added dynamically so otherwise they wouldn't have the event bound to them
$sortable.on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  // this does disable the default behaviour of checking/unchecking the box
  e.preventDefault();
  const $this = $(this);
  // this doesn't check/uncheck the box at all, but setting a global variable to $this and doing it via console does work
  $this.prop('checked', !$this.prop('checked'));
});
```

I have tried a more typical approach using a flag, however there seems to be some race condition (or whatever it's called because if I am not mistaken js is monothreaded) and the function is run twice anyway:

```
let checked = false;
$sortable.on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  if (checked) return;
  // this is output twice, which is not what we are after
  console.log('running');
  checked = true;
  // here ideally we would set the value of the checkbox
  checked = false;
});
```

I have checked for any problematic events bound to the inputs using `$._data($checkboxes[0], 'events')` but other than a bootstrap tooltip (mouseover and mouseout events) and of course the change event there's nothing else fishy.

**edit:** Basically it seems that the sortable widget produces a separate click event when you click anywhere in the div or its children. That's the reason why click/change is fired twice.

*My question is:* how can I discriminate between the originator of the event so that if it's the sortable plugin the event can be ignored, while if it's the listener I set up the checkbox does change its value (and I perform any other actions I may want to perform when the checkbox is actually checked)?

Comment: which kind of touch device are you using ?

Comment: @Buisson just my Android phone, but the issue has been reported for some users using our site on "mobile" (I wasn't told exactly what kind of touch device)

Comment: Maybe you have added two listeners of click for this checkbox ?

Comment: @Buisson it doesn't appear so: `$._data($sortable[0], 'events')` only shows one click event for the `input[type="checkbox"]` selector.

Comment: probably because, your sortable and checkbox are both  triggering click event ,

Comment: @AhmedSunny that's what I was thinking, but what can I do to make it as if the checkbox was clicked only once? As I described in my post I can't seem to control the value of the checkbox and `e.stopImmediatePropagation` isn't preventing the click event from being fired again (I guess because technically the're different listeners).

Comment: why don't you use change event , 
or use id instead of $sortable ,

Comment: @AhmedSunny change event is fired twice if click is fired twice. I don't see what you mean "use id instead of $sortable"? Not sure what you're suggesting there.

Answer (score 0):

try touchend and if it works for click as well use the following way , else separate it

```
$sortable.on("touchend click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
    if(e.type == 'touchend'){
        $(this).off('click');
        // your function
    }
});
```

else try this for both

```
let checked = false;
$sortable.on("touchend click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
   if(e.type == "touchend") {
    checked = true;
    // your function
  }
  else if(e.type == "click" && !checked ) {
    // your function
  }
});
```

Comment: touchend is not fired apparently

Comment: first try 'touchend touchcancel' and if that does'nt work use  use addEventListener to add touchend event to your $sortable.

Comment: Not fired either.